# Delete illegal router from network

Tags: debian, router, mac-address, arp, nftables

I have a default gateway with IP address 192.168.1.1 and MAC address 5c:77:76:6e:0d:7b. It is my only wi fi modem router from which I receive internet.

But in input nftables logs I saw another one router with the same IP address and different MAC address `5c:77:77:6e:0d:7b.` This unknown router sends pages which I didn't open (spam).

I tried two ways to solve this problem:

1. Set up static arp cache. Now my arp cache looks like this:

   `arp -a mw40.home (192.168.1.1) at 5c:77:76:6e:0d:7b [ether] PERM on wlo1`
2. Drop packets from illegal router in etc/ nftables.conf:

   `ether saddr 5c:77:77:6e:0d:7b counter drop;`

But after the second step, I lost my internet connection.

My questions:

1. What is happening in this piece of log (below)?
2. How are the two routers communicating with each other?
3. How I can remove from my network the illegal router with `MAC address 5c:77:77:6e:0d:7b?`

```
    Sep  1 15:16:03 flower kernel: [  133.359821] New Input packets: IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=b8:81:98:cb:ef:a8:5c:77:77:6e:0d:7b:08:00 SRC=85.159.224.52 DST=192.168.1.2 LEN=76 TOS=0x18 PREC=0x60 TTL=49 ID=4873 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=123 DPT=47244 LEN=56 
    Sep  1 15:16:11 flower kernel: [  141.053122] New Input packets: IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=b8:81:98:cb:ef:a8:5c:77:77:6e:0d:7b:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.2 LEN=185 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=32498 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=53 DPT=56881 LEN=165 
    Sep  1 15:16:12 flower kernel: [  141.660330] New Input packets: IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=b8:81:98:cb:ef:a8:5c:77:77:6e:0d:7b:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.2 LEN=111 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=32521 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=53 DPT=36247 LEN=91 
    Sep  1 15:16:12 flower kernel: [  141.694208] New Input packets: IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=b8:81:98:cb:ef:a8:5c:77:77:6e:0d:7b:08:00 SRC=172.67.68.8 DST=192.168.1.2 LEN=52 TOS=0x18 PREC=0x60 TTL=56 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=50048 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
    Sep  1 15:16:12 flower kernel: [  141.722991] New Input packets: IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=b8:81:98:cb:ef:a8:5c:77:77:6e:0d:7b:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.2 LEN=147 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=32522 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=53 DPT=51721 LEN=127 
    Sep  1 15:16:12 flower kernel: [  141.743011] New Input packets: IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=b8:81:98:cb:ef:a8:5c:77:76:6e:0d:7b:08:00 SRC=172.67.68.8 DST=192.168.1.2 LEN=40 TOS=0x18 PREC=0x60 TTL=56 ID=3764 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=50048 WINDOW=66 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
    Sep  1 15:16:12 flower kernel: [  141.743028] New Input packets: IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=b8:81:98:cb:ef:a8:5c:77:76:6e:0d:7b:08:00 SRC=172.67.68.8 DST=192.168.1.2 LEN=2840 TOS=0x18 PREC=0x60 TTL=56 ID=3765 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=50048 WINDOW=66 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

More logs from router with illegal MAC address here:
 [nftables logs from illegal router](http://savetext.online/nftlog.txt)

Comment: why don't you simply turn off the illegal router?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Routers often have multiple virtual network interfaces, and the MAC address that gets assigned to these is made by flipping some bits of the hardware MAC address.

So the "illegal router" you see is probably another virtual interface of your "legal router". And if you block the packets (which are "legal" packets) then your "legal" router will stop to work.

If there really was an "illegal router" somewhere in your home, you should be able to physically see and touch it, shouldn't you?

Comment: Dirkt, thank you very much for answer! I have only one router in my home. I didn't know about virtual interface. But from this MAC address 5c:77:77:6e:0d:7b I receive spam. Have I a posibility to turn off virtual interface and left only one interface with MAC address 5c:77:76:6e:0d:7b?

Comment: How do you know you "receive spam from a MAC address"? Do you mean "unsolicited email" in the sense of "spam"? But anyhow: become root on your router, check all the interfaces, and find out what this interface is good for.

Comment: I see traffic in input nftables log (pages) I didn't open. I was thinking it was spam. In my router's home page (192.168.1.1) I don't see info about interfaces. I have simple home router Alcatel. Maybe I should install special programm (for Linux Debian) to make my router accessible from command line?

Comment: Assuming you mean web pages: Nothing can "send" web pages. Your browser **requests** web pages. Any non-requested packets of "web pages" would just be ignored. If you see some TCP traffic where you don't understand where it is from, you can figure out the program on your computer that thinks it needs it. And today, lots of "professional" programs (Microsoft) use analytics, which make HTTP requests.

Comment: The UI of your home router won't tell to all the virtual interfaces. Either you can become root on this router, and look, or you can't. You can replace the router with a router with open firmware like OpenWRT, then you can.

Comment: Dirkt, thank you very much for solution! I see that I can't become root on my router and I will use OpenWRT and continue improve my firewall settings for blocking some programms. Thank you!